# Apache not loading php

Tags: apache2, php

So I've been reading posts about this same issue for some time now and came to no conclusion.

I developed a website on php 7 on windows , everything was working correctly on localhost with php built-in server so I assumed , great let's put it on the server only problem is that either

```
<?php require 'get_yards.php';?>
```

this line get's completely ignored on my index.php

Here's whats inside get_yards.php.

```
<?php
include "/resources/library/get_yards2.php";
?>
```

and if I ignore this 'middle-man' I get a

> GET http://website/bicker.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

here's whats inside get_yards2.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php');
// Get the DB connection settings
$dbHost = $config["db"]["server"]["host"];
$dbUser = $config["db"]["server"]["username"];
$dbPass = $config["db"]["server"]["password"];
$dbName = $config["db"]["server"]["dbname"];
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$dbUser, "PWD"=>$dbPass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbHost, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = "SELECT YardId,Yard FROM YWBYard"; 
$params = array();
$options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if( $result === false){
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
else {
    $numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result); 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['YardId']===1){
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://website/".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }
        elseif($row['YardId']===2){
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://website/bicker.php".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }
        else{
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://website/crick.php".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }      
    }
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I'm open to trying anything at this point.

Here are the server error logs

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/resources/library/get_yards.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/get_yards.php on line 2

so I tried using this instead

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/resources/library/get_yards.php';
?>
```

the same server error (GET 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR))

Comment: Hi Gabriel, is php 7 installed on your live server?

Comment: Yes it is , http://imgur.com/a/q65FB here's the phpinfo , it also has sqlsrv installed , looking at server logs i'm getting PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/resources/library/get_yards.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/get_yards.php on line 2

Comment: Have you checked that your permissions are set correctly? Please could you paste the get_yards.php file?

Comment: The "get_yards.php" file is in the main post, i just called it get_yards2 here to avoid confusion and I don't think permissions should be a problem since it reads the index.php html part until It gets to the php ? but maybe i'm wrong

Comment: In that case the second line in get_yards will be require_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php'); and that is where the error is coming from

Comment: Any idea what might be wrong with it ? Because I'm 100% sure the file is there

Comment: Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

Comment: Have you tried just require instead of require_once?

Comment: I just did , still the same error even if I comment it I still get the stupid GET 500 error

Comment: Okay do you have .htaccess file please post it

Comment: Alright I managed to fix the paths , now I'm getting a different error "PHP Fatal error:  sqlsrv_connect: Unknown exception caught. in /var/www/resources/library/yards.php on line 9" which would be "$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbHost, $connectionInfo);" this line but i'm pretty sure my info is correct.